# C# Console.WriteLine() Not working Outside of Main()

Tags: c#

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I haven't been able to find any answers to the issue I am having. I'm working with the following block of code:

```
IPGlobalProperties computerProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
Console.WriteLine("Interface information for {0}.{1}     ",
        computerProperties.HostName, computerProperties.DomainName);
foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in nics)
{
    IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
    Console.WriteLine(adapter.Description);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Empty.PadLeft(adapter.Description.Length, '='));
    Console.WriteLine("  Interface type ... : {0}", adapter.NetworkInterfaceType);
    Console.WriteLine("  Physical Address ........... : {0}",
               adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("  Is receive only.............. : {0}", adapter.IsReceiveOnly);
    Console.WriteLine("             Multicast......... : {0}", adapter.SupportsMulticast);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

When I run without debugging, and this code is within the Main() method, the `Console.WriteLine()` prints the output. However, when I put this into a `public static void` class, the output is blank. Can anyone explain why this happens and what I should do instead. I'm still learning C# so I'm sure this is a beginner's mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After you place the logic in a separate method are you calling it in your main method? Make sure you call the method e.g. `public static void test()` is called within `static main(string[] args){ test() }`

Comment: It's now apparent that I've made a beginner's mistake by not calling my method from within `static main()`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that the code in your other class is never executed. You don't need the class to be public static and void (not sure if that's possible), but you want the method you're using to be public static void.

This is what you want your other class to look like:

```
public class OtherClass {

    public static void Method() {

        // Console.WriteLine code here

    }
}
```

And then your main should call that Method:

```
public class OriginalClass {

    public static void Main(String[] args) {

        OtherClass.Method();

    }

}
```

If you meant other method/function instead of class, it will look like this:

```
public class OriginalClass {

    public static void Main(String[] args) {

        Method();

    }

    public static void Method() {

        // Console.WriteLine code here

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I feel pretty foolish making a beginner's mistake like that. Definitely learned a lot just now from your post. It was even worth the downvote!

Comment: @StephenRoss Don't feel foolish at all! Making those mistakes and recognizing it makes you that much more likely to get it right the next time :)

Answer (score 0):

"Main" is a special method in .NET environment. It is a "entry point" of every .NET program.

When yours application/program run, Main will be invoke and every command in this method will be execute.

If you put your code into other method or class and you don't call it inside Main, obviously nothing happen. So if you want run other method, you must call it inside Main.

Hope it useful.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just now realizing that I wasn't calling it from within Main().